# Connecting HumongouS.io to MongoDB on Openshift

Tags: mongodb, openshift

I am having issues connecting HumongouS service to my MongoDB on Openshift free plan.
First I get the "server refuse to connect " error which I understand I need to whitelist the ip address given by HumongouS. But it does not look like openshift allows this functionality.
Second, there is the SSL option but not sure how do I set up MongoDB  to use SSL in Openshift.
Please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Security Groups - Change Inbound settings to the I.P.address with which you want to connect
By this, it enables the EC2 instance - Mongo server to allow connection with the given IP address.
Whitelisting means allowing Custom TCP connection to Port 27017 with the IP Adddress (Inbound connection)